# Store kit In app purchases can’t get responsed

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I’m writing in app purchases app which can’t get responded and not sure why iTunesConnect are all set too and I’m sure my product id are same

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

class InAppPurchases: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate {

    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print(response.products)
    }

    private override init() { }
    static let shared = InAppPurchases()

    func getProducts() {
        let products: Set = ["com.google.sites.xxx.app.product"]
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: products)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }

}
```

Calling get product in viewdidload and get empty set
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you get any values in the `invalidProductIdentifiers` of your response?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes it’s in invalidProductIndetifiers. dose that means my iTunes connection has something wrong. IAP current status is ‘ready to submit’

Comment: Yes, it means that those product identifiers aren't valid for this application; "Ready to submit" is an OK status.  Are you running on a real device (not the simulator?) Have you signed all of the tax and banking contracts?

Comment: @Paulw11 but how to fix that. I’m sure product are the same since I copy it from browser. Is that something with product ID I’m using ‘com.google.sites.xxx.app.product’

Comment: I can't say; it is certainly an odd id, but as long as it is unique it shouldn't matter. Make sure you are using the product id and not the reference name.  Are you testing on a phone or the simulator?

Comment: @Paulw11 I’m testing it on my phone. Don’t remember set the tax and banking contracts I’m try to checking but not not found yet

Comment: Its under "Agreements, tax & banking" in AppStore connect (which appears to be down for me at the moment)

Comment: @Paulw11 yes it’a hard since apple redirect that link to an non existing page yesterday but finally.. that is the answer if u want sandbox tests u need to provide that info before. really really appreciate your help.